# Is this a threaded tap? If so, what is the best way to unscrew it without damaging it?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, water, faucet, taps

So this is the tap I have and I’d like to attach an accessory to it. I believe it is threaded and I should be able to unscrew the existing head to be able to use the threads, but I don’t know how to remove it. The plier (correct word?) tool that I have has sharp teeth and it’s scratching and damaging the tap. I’ve tried several grippy, nonslip layers between them to avoid damage but it’s still slipping or scratching the tap. Any suggestions?
[image: faucet]
[image: the tool and the cloth]

Comment: Most of those that I have seen can be turned by hand. Make sure you are turning the correct direction - it may be reverse-threaded.

Comment: Solder joints are also common in fabricated fixtures.

Comment: I love it when an answer is provided on how to do something and credit is not given.

Comment: By "tap" do you mean the aerator/ diffuser on the outlet ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The thread was a two-sided male screwing to both sides (female), the tap and the nozzle thing. All I needed was a larger tool and some more strength.

[image: tap]

[image: thread]

Answer (score 2):

I will use a piece of leather if I don't want to damage the finish. Think old leather belt if you don't have any scraps of leather.

Answer (score 0):

The curving spigot probably is a press fit and would not unscrew from the valve body. Afik all valve bodies of this type are removed from below. You or an assistant holds the valve body (the part you can see above the lavatory) with a hand and you use a "basin wrench" to remove a nut from below.

Comment: Uh, so no way without the basin wrench? :(

Comment: If you have room, you can loosen the nut with the angled slip-joint pliers (often called "channel locks") that you have

Comment: It was in fact screwable.

Comment: What was "screwable", the spigot on top or the nut below?

Comment: I’ll post the details now.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the threads are internal, as in female. Have a look at the water screen(also called an aerator) and see if you can unscrew it.